# How would i read lines only starting with B or R using Python

Tags: python-3.x, db2, db2-luw

Op Obj Timestamp+Sequence Type Dev Earliest Log Current Log  Backup ID

---

B  D  20200518123514001   N    D  S0000026.LOG S0000026.LOG

---

Contains 4 tablespace(s):

00001 SYSCATSPACE
 00002 USERSPACE1
 00003 GOSALES_TS
 00004 SYSTOOLSPACE

---

```
Comment: DB2 BACKUP GSDB ONLINE
```

Start Time: 20200518123514

End Time: 20200518123515

```
 Status: A
```

---

EID: 365 Location: C:\Users\db2admin\Desktop\sales_backup

Comment: What is the exact question and where is your code where you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse "list history" output,  you should perform a query against SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY view.

This way you can easily get only the interest columns and apply filters to capture only the desired types of records you want:

```
SELECT * from SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY WHERE OPERATION IN ('B', 'R')
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022351.html

Regards, 
Samuel